# My webRTC app is not connecting to Remote system

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

I am running my webRTC app in HTTPS server. it is running properly, But it is not taking Remote system Details(SDP).
Both Local system(PC1) and Remote system(PC2) are not getting connected both are taking Local SDP values only.

The code [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/webrtc/samples/gh-pages/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/js/main.js).

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please review the [ask] section and [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that the remote machine and your machine are not able to find each other. They need a way to lookup each other and find a path on the network to connect, [that is what STUN does](https://www.avaya.com/blogs/archives/2014/08/understanding-webrtc-media-connections-ice-stun-and-turn.html).

Instead of settings `const servers = null`, use one of the free STUN servers, like say, Google's, like this

```
const servers = {'iceServers': [{'urls':'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]}
```

On a related note, you can make use of the [RTCPeerConnection.defaultIceServers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/defaultIceServers) when you need to set common iceServers in all the `RTCPeerConnection` objects. So, this will also work.

```
RTCPeerConnection.defaultIceServers = [{'urls':'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]
```